# Async await support in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await

I have been looking at `async` and `await`. I really like it.

I m curious if there is support for `async` and `await` in Entity Framework?

> Entity Framework meets the use case of async/await support and if I
>   want to use async/await with Entity Framework, how would I do it?

ie: I was able to have a wrapper around redis (booksleeve).

So when I have a repository pattern, can I use async / await with EF? how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Direct support of async and await was a [highly requested suggestion on UserVoice for Entity Framework](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2726060-async-await-supported-asynchronous-calls), and is scheduled to be included in EF 6.

Answer (score 1):

Get EF 6 from NuGet in the NuGet console PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Pre
You will need to add and remove some references